# Dropdown in jqxgrid cells

Tags: javascript, json, jqxgrid

I'm trying to populate a table in Jqxgrid containing two columns: one with client and one with a dropbox containing groupnames.

This part sucessfully fetches data to be used in the dropdownbox. Chrome logs it to the console sucessfully:

```
var groupsource =
{
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'groupname', type: 'string'},
        { name: 'groupid', type: 'integer'}
    ],
    id: 'GroupID',
    url: 'testje.php',
    cache: false,
};
```

This part also seems to work fine:

```
var employeesAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(groupsource, {
    autoBind: true,
    beforeLoadComplete: function (records) {
        var data = new Array();
        // update the loaded records. Dynamically add EmployeeName and EmployeeID fields. 
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            var employee = records[i];
            employee.GroupName = employee.groupname;
            employee.GroupID = employee.groupid;
            data.push(employee);
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```

This part however, doesn't seem to load the datasource right? None of the dropdowns contains any data. When I log to the console, no groupnames seem to be in it:

```
var source =
{
    datatype: "json",
    datafields: [
        { name: 'GroupName', value: 'GroupID', values: { source: employeesAdapter.records, value: 'GroupID', name: 'GroupName' } },
        { name: 'client'}
    ],
    url: 'singlesgrid_data.php',
    cache: false,
    updaterow: function (rowid, rowdata){
        // synchronize with the server - send update command
        $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'singlesgrid_data.php',
            data: {'update' : 'true', 'client' : rowdata.client, 'groupid' : rowdata.groupid},
            success: function (data, status, xhr){
                // update command is executed.
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Obviously this output won't work either:

```
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);        
$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid(
{
    source: dataAdapter,
    editable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: true,
    columns: [
        { text: 'Groep', datafield: 'GroupID', displayfield: 'GroupName', columntype: 'dropdownlist', width: 150},
        { text: 'client', datafield: 'client', width: 250}
    ]
});
```

Can someone tell me what's going wrong with populating the datafields in the source var?

Answer (score 0):

the solution is:

```
var groupsource =
        {
            datatype: "json",
            datafields: [
                { name: 'groupname', type: 'string'},
                { name: 'groupid', type: 'integer'}
            ],
            id: 'GroupID',
            url: 'testje.php',
            cache: false,
            async: false
         };
```

Also you might look at this example: [jQWidgets Grid DropDownList Editor](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/gridkeyvaluescolumnwitharray.htm?arctic)
Hope this helps you.

Comment: I've tried this before.

Unfortunately, this doesn't solve it. The dropdownboxes remain empty...

Answer (score 0):

Did you get anywhere with this, I have a similar issue, but have you tried the `autoBind: true` on your dataAdapter:

```
var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source, { autoBind: true });
```

This translated values in the fields into actual names for me, but it did not list any values available for the field that were not present in the grid.